# Getting an image dimensions

Tags: javascript, image, function, dimensions

I've got a problem with getting image dimensions. I want to know the width and height of image without its loading into document. At present I have code as follows:

```
 function getImageSize (path) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.name = path;
  var d = image.onload = function() {
   var w = this.width;
   var h = this.height;
   return {width : w, height : h};
  }();
  image.src = path;
  return d;
 }
```

If I call that function, I get object containing undefined in both index (w, h). I've tried not call onload handler by exclude parenthesis (8 line) but what I get is function code.

Note that if I call `alert(w)` inside onload handler body, I can see width of picture but outside it not.

Does someone know how to solve that problem? How can I get image dimension?

Answer (score 6):

This block

```
var d = image.onload = function() {
   var w = this.width;
   var h = this.height;
   return {width : w, height : h};
}();
```

looks very fishy. This is actually executing the function **immediately** and assigning the object `{width : w, height : h}` to `image.onload` and `d`. `w` and `h` will contain the width and height of the **window** because `this` will refer to `window`.

You have to assign the function to `image.onload`, not execute it. The reason you have to assign the function is that it takes time to load the image and the callback gets called once the image was loaded. The whole process is **asynchronous**. That also means that you **cannot** return the dimensions of the image from `getImageSize`. You have to make it accept a callback, which you have to call in the `load` callback.

For example:

```
function getImageSize (path, callback) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.name = path;
  image.onload = function() {
   callback({width : this.width, height : this.height};
  }
  image.src = path;
};
```

and call the function with

```
getImageSize('path/to/image', function(dim) {
    // do something with dim.width, dim.height
});
```

---

Have a look at the first part of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/218196) to learn about the difference of synchronous and asynchronous code, and the role of callbacks.

Comment: As I said, you cannot return the dimensions. Quoting myself: *"That also means that you **cannot** return the dimensions of the image from `getImageSize`"*. All code that needs access to the dimensions has to go or be called from the callback.

Answer (score 0):

`onload` is an asynchronous call and cannot return anything useful out of the calling function.

You will have to use a global variable and timer check to wait for the function to complete and then access the values.